# Notable decisive grandmaster-level games where only pawns were captured?

Tags: captures

Are there any notable Grandmaster-level games that were won with only pawns captured, but no higher level pieces?

Comment: I edited from "no losses" to "no exchange", because I think that was what you meant.

Comment: "No exchange" is definitely clearer. Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1442039) is a 30.5-move decisive game with _no_ captures, which [Tim Krabbé](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records/records.htm) says is the record. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer That's a really interesting game! Note, though, that it's not Grandmaster-level: White's highest FIDE rating was 2006.

Answer (score 11):

Last week GM Nigel Short [tweeted](https://twitter.com/nigelshortchess/status/802892636486975489):

> Not sure I have won too many games without a single piece or pawn being captured. Short-Derakshani, Beautiful Minds Krulich Cup, rd 10.

I can't find PGN of that game yet and am at work, but you can replay it at https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/krulich-cup-2016/10/1/1 - all 32 pieces still on the board, until at move 20 black removed the last escape square of his own queen. After 21.Ng2 attacking it, black resigned.

Moves, taken from [here](http://chess-db.com/public/pinfo.jsp?id=12500330):

```
[FEN ""]
1. c4 e5 2. e3 Nc6 3. a3 Nf6 4. Nc3 g6 5. d3 Bg7 6. g4 h6 7. Bg2 d6 8. h3 Be6 9. Nd5 Qd7 10. Ne2 Nd8 11. b3 Nh7 12. e4 c6 13. Ne3 Qe7 14. Bb2 Bd7 15. d4 O-O 16. d5 c5 17. Qc2 Qh4 18. Nc3 b6 19. O-O-O Nb7 20. Bf1 Ng5 21. Ng2 1-0
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. A quick search came up with this game: [Zapata vs. Anand](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/the-shortest-gm-game-ever).

```
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 d6 4. Nf3 Nxe4 5. Nc3 Bf5 6. Qe2
```

My initial thought was to look for the game Christiansen vs. Karpov. However, that game had one set of minor pieces exchanged before Karpov's blunder and resignation.

```
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 b6 4. a3 Ba6 5. Qc2 Bb7 6. Nc3 c5 7. e4 cxd4 8. Nd4 Nc6 9. Nc6 Bc6 10. Bf4 Nh5 11. Be3 Bd6 12. Qd1
```