# What is the fastest loss by a GM in a FIDE classical game?

Tags: checkmate, records, grandmaster, master-games, resigning

What is the shortest FIDE classical game a grandmaster lost? It can be either resigning or checkmate. The opponent doesn't necessarily need to be GM. Forfeits don't count. Only serious games count, instead of resigning after one or two moves as a form of protest like [this](https://en.chessbase.com/post/gibraltar-flash)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_chess#Shortest_game You can find more candidates here.

Answer (score 17):

I also did some research and found this game [IM Hagen Poetsch](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/24615137) vs [GM Yair Kraidman](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/2800187) in [Vienna Open 2013](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=2465327) where black resigned in 4 moves. Black has forgotten that white recaptured with the Queen not the Knight.

But i don't know if there are shorter than this

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Vienna Chess Open 2013"]
[Site "Vienna AUT"]
[Date "2013.08.19"]
[EventDate "2013.08.17"]
[Round "3"]
[Result "1-0"]
[White "Hagen Poetsch"]
[Black "Yair Kraidman"]
[ECO "B27"]
[WhiteElo "2446"]
[BlackElo "2254"]
[PlyCount "8"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 g6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Qxd4 Nc6 1-0
```

Comment: What? Was this played OTB? How can you "forget" this unless you premove?

Comment: @infinitezero this is otb. could be because GM is very old and rating in 2200s (declining) https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessplayer?pid=124978&kpage=1#reply3

Answer (score 10):

From my answer to [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/15997/9025) on decisive GM games with only pawn captures, at 6 moves, this is probably still the shortest: [Zapata vs. Anand](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/the-shortest-gm-game-ever).

```
[fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 d6 4. Nf3 Nxe4 5. Nc3 Bf5 6. Qe2
```